# Variation Dijkstra considering 0 as a weight

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra on adjacency matrix where 0 has the meaning of weight instead of "no connection". I'm quite struggling on how to modify the original algorithm, Is there any clue that could help me to find out the way?
implementation:

```
#define V 3
int minDistance(int dist[], bool sptSet[]){
    int min = INT_MAX, min_index;
 
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
        if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
            min = dist[v], min_index = v;
 
    return min_index;
}
 
void dijkstra(int graph[V][V], int src){
    int dist[V]; 
 
    bool sptSet[V]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false;
 
    dist[src] = 0;
 
    for (int count = 0; count < V - 1; count++) {
        int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet);
 
        sptSet[u] = true;
 
        
        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
            if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX
                && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v])
                dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
    }
 
}
```

for example if I give in input:

```
0, 0, 0
1, 2, 1
2, 9, 3
```

the minimum path should be 0 lenght, instead I get 2147483647 which is the INT_MAX.

Source is node 0, and destinations are all the other nodes.

Comment: Does this mean all nodes are connected to all nodes or is the lack of connection indicated some other way? I don't think there is anything in Dijkstra that disallows zero weights. It's only negative weights that are a problem.

Comment: Exactly, all nodes are connected. If you consider 0s in the original algorithm, It will skip that path and Will choose other paths that are not null, which Is wrong because 0 Is Always the minimum

Comment: add 1 to all the weights?

Comment: Can you provide the implementation that you have which skips the path with an edge equal to zero? Dijkstra's algorithm should be perfectly fine with edges that have the value of zero; these edges don't need to be handled separately.

Comment: Dijkstra with zeros works fine. Canonically the "there is no arc here" matrix entry is infinity.

Comment: Thanks for adding the implementation, but we still don't know what is the source and what is the destination of the minimum path you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the implementation you provided, the condition for updating the distance to a node is:

> if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v])

The second part is the one that is causing your code to skip when finding an edge with a cost equal to zero:

> graph[u][v]

I assume that your code is written in C++. Thus, this check means *true* if the value is non-zero, and *false* otherwise. You need to update the condition to remove this part:

> if (!sptSet[v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v])

In this case, the algorithm should work fine.

If you use this update and still need to indicate the case of no edge, then you can set its value to INT_MAX rather than zero.

Comment: Can you share an example with the source and destination which is giving a wrong answer?

Comment: Great! Can you please upvote my answer and mark it as the correct one?